# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser' when opening SQL files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly, visual-studio-express

I have a ASP.Net MVC application built using Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web

I have a SQL file attached to my project. When I double click it inside VS I get

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser,
>   version 14.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, ... the system cannot find the
>   file specified

Most of the SQL tools don't work in VS but I'd like to be able to open these files in VS at least.

The file `Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll` exists in a number of places

in folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLCommon\140`

I have file `Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll`, version 14.0.500.182

In this folder is also have a file called `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlCommonPackage.pkgdef` which has these lines:

> [$RootKey$\RuntimeConfiguration\dependentAssembly\bindingRedirection{23E68C48-194A-4397-A74B-1ACFCC76E0AC}]
>   "Name"="Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser" 
>   "PublicKeyToken"="89845dcd8080cc91"
>   "Culture"="neutral" 
>   "oldVersion"="13.0.0.0-14.0.0.0"
>   "newVersion"="14.100.0.0" 
>   "CodeBase"="$PackageFolder$\Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll"

I've tried changing the newVersion in here to match the various versions lying around but the error doesn't change

I also have many versions of this file in c:\windows\assembly (none of them version 14)

I don't actually have a version 14.100 anywhere as far as I can tell.

Does anyone know how to fix visual studio so it uses one of the DLL versions I actually have?

Comment: Hey, have you found any solution to this? I'm facing the same.

Comment: No. It' annoying. I ended up changing the default editor to notepad++

Comment: I just installed SSDT for VS 2017 and this works OK in there.